# Output const char * with delimiters

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

I have an issue where I would like to take a string that is created from a function that has multiple lines where I need to get the all the new line delimiters for later formatting in Python.

For example:

```
const char * getInfoLogFunction()
{
    static char buffer[4096];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 4096, NULL, buffer);

    const char * compileStatus = buffer;
    return compileStatus
}
```

Now compileStatus points to a string such as:

> This is a string.
>
> With multiple lines.

Later I need to send compileStatus to an application that will put the entire string into 1 cell of tab separated table. With Python I then need to format the single line string back into multiple lines. Which I can do easily if the delimiters were in the string but they are not.

Is there a way I can get the string from compileStatus and have it formatted so it will have all the delimiters present?

I've found la number of examples when strings are created implicitly such as:

```
myString = R"xyz(Some String)xyz"
```

But I can't find a way to format a string referenced by const char * that was generated by a function.

thanks

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). The function already returns a string with line breaks in it.  It sounds like the application is then stripping the line breaks when displaying the string in the table. Nothing the original function can do about that. The application should not strip the line breaks, or should remember the original string so it can parse it when needed.

Comment: This is also really poor design. Every call to this function retrospectively overrides all strings returned previously as a side effect.

Comment: Thanks Remy I think that is the case.

Baum I'm not sure how that is a design flaw? In this case previously returned strings have no importance since only the last compile log would count as far as a user is concerned. A user would write a shader and if there were errors he would be notified.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at this code:

```
const char * getInfoLogFunction()
{
    static char buffer[4096];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 4096, NULL, buffer);

    const char * compileStatus = buffer; // <--- Here
    return compileStatus; 
}
```

This function returns `compileStatus`, which is a pointer to `buffer`. As a result, every time you call this function, you get back a pointer to the same character buffer. So, for example, if I say

```
const char* call1Result = getInfoLogFunction();

// Time passes, then...
const char* call2Result = getInfoLogFunction();
```

I'll have two pointers to the same buffer, so the string pointed at by `call1Result` will be exactly the same as the string pointed at by `call2Result`. This could cause real problems down the line if I wanted to store copies of all the logs over time, for example.

An easy way to fix this would be to have the function return a `std::string`, which makes a deep copy of the string used to initialize it. That means that future calls to `getInfoLogFunction` won't share the same underlying buffer. You can then pass it into Python by using the `string::c_str()` member function get a raw C-style array back.